# Is moneypunct Object International?

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, currency, typename

Say I have a templatized function that takes a [`moneypunct`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/moneypunct):

```
template <typename T>
void foo(const T& bar);
```

I can use `typename T:char_type` to determine the first `moneypunct` template argument (whether I'm dealing with a `moneypunct<char>` or a `moneypunct<wchar_t>`.) But how can I determine whether the second template argument is `true` or `false` (`moneypunct<char, true>` or `moneypunct<char, false>`?)

Is the only way to accomplish this to redesign my function to:

```
template <typename CharT, typename International = false>
void foo(const moneypunct<CharT, International>& bar);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to take a `moneypunct`, this would definitely be the best, clearest solution:

```
template <typename CharT, typename International = false>
void foo(const moneypunct<CharT, International>& bar);
```

However, you can still determine both template arguments from the original with a type trait:

```
template <typename> struct isInternational;

template <typename CharT, bool International>
struct isInternational<std::moneypunct<CharT, International>>
: std::integral_constant<bool, International>
{ }
```

Which you can use:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(const T& bar) {
    // this won't compile if T is not a std::moneypunct
    std::cout << isInternational<T>::value << std::endl;
}
```